# Amazon SNS not working

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have imported 'aws-autoloader.php' and used AWS-SDK php library

```
$sns = SnsClient::factory(array('key'    => "******",
                                           'secret' => "*******",
                                           'region' => "us-east-1"));
```

But I cant able to get any responds. I already used this key and secret in AWS S3 but here its not working help me regarding this.